# Mongo DB Aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mango DB, can anyone explain how to get the below stats from this in a single query result

- It sould group by "lastActionTimestamp"
- We should get total count of "extractionFinished" ,  "transformationFinished", "loadFinished", failed and status=duplicate docs. Can anyone help on this?

Sample Data Set:

```
   "migration" : {
            "sourceSystem" : "Test",
            "targetSystem" : "Test2",
            "lastAction" : "load finished",
            "lastActionTimestamp" : ISODate("2018-04-28T19:08:00.335Z"),
            "extractionStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-14T02:22:46.882Z"),
            "extractionFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-14T02:22:46.882Z"),
            "failed" : false
            "status" : "Valid",
            "deltaStatus" : false,
            "transformationStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-22T14:33:46.020Z"),
            "transformationFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-22T14:33:46.023Z"),
            "loadStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-28T19:07:58.803Z"),
            "loadFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-28T19:08:00.336Z"),
            "failureReason" : ""
        }

        "migration" : {
            "sourceSystem" : "Test",
            "targetSystem" : "Test2",
            "lastAction" : "load finished",
            "lastActionTimestamp" : ISODate("2018-04-28T19:08:00.335Z"),
            "extractionStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-14T02:22:46.882Z"),
            "extractionFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-14T02:22:46.882Z"),
            "failed" : true
            "status" : "Valid",
            "deltaStatus" : false,
            "transformationStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-22T14:33:46.020Z"),
            "transformationFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-22T14:33:46.023Z"),

            "failureReason" : "Some Issue"
        }
        "migration" : {
            "sourceSystem" : "Test",
            "targetSystem" : "Test2",
            "lastAction" : "load finished",
            "lastActionTimestamp" : ISODate("2018-04-28T19:08:00.335Z"),
            "extractionStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-14T02:22:46.882Z"),
            "extractionFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-14T02:22:46.882Z"),
            "failed" : False
            "status" : "Duplicate",
            "deltaStatus" : false,
            "transformationStarted" : ISODate("2018-04-22T14:33:46.020Z"),
            "transformationFinished" : ISODate("2018-04-22T14:33:46.023Z"),

            "failureReason" : ""
        }
```

Expected Output:

Extraction Finished : 3
Transformation Finished: 3
Load Finished : 1
Duplicate :1
Failed:1

Comment: What do you mean - by get total count of "extractionFinished" , "transformationFinished", "loadFinished", failed and status=duplicate docs? Please add expected output

Comment: Thanks Astro for your reply.. I edited the expected output..thanks